# python csv delimiter issue

Tags: python, csv

I have this script which writes to csv file:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import codecs
import cStringIO
import sys

class UTF8Recoder:

    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

with open('agajan.csv', 'w') as f:
    uW = UnicodeWriter(f, delimiter=' ')
    row = ["agaja asa; . ' a", "t, o , ,rayev", "bazargeldiyevich"]
    uW.writerow(row)
```

The problem is instead of three columns it writes more columns than needed. In my string there could be any character, but I would like to write it correctly. How can I manage this?
For Example: `row = ["agaja asa; . ' a", "t, o , ,rayev", "columns"]` adding semicolon to last column `"colu;mns"` wil create new column

Answer (score 0):

I changed this to a tab delimited format:

```
with open('agajan.csv', 'w') as f:
    #uW = UnicodeWriter(f, delimiter=' ')
    uW = UnicodeWriter(f, delimiter="\t")
    row = ["agaja asa; . ' a", "t, o , ,rayev", "colu;mns"]
    uW.writerow(row)
    row1 = ["I", "am", "ironman"]
    uW.writerow(row1)
```

When I viewed the output in LibreOffice as a tab separated file it worked as expected.

I don't think using space as a delimiter is a good option in this case since your fields will almost certainly contain spaces. As such, I believe the space as the delimiter is probably what is creating the extra fields, not the semi-colon.

Comment: What OS/Version of Python are you using? Also, what method are you using to verify the file (e.g. opening in Excel). My output was as follows (I have used <\t> for tab, <\n> for newline so I can print it easily here): `agaja asa; . ' a<\t>t, o , ,rayev<\t>colu;mns<\n>
I<\t>am<\t>ironman<\n>`. This is 3 columns in each of the two lines which appears to be what you requested. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Python 2.7.3.